Плохое воспроизведение музыки | Android
Сделал при загрузки приложения новогоднюю музыку, она играет через одно место, (слышно ооочеень плохо, она шумит, чуть чуть слышно саму песню, потом вообще выключается) (Песня нормальная, другие тоже так) (Класс - MediaPlayer)
else if(status == 4) {
         ShowLoading();
         music = MediaPlayer.create(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wham_last_christmas);
         music.start();
         status1.setText("Загрузка игры...");


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

все просто - музыку нельзя воспроизводить на главном потоке. запускайте ее асинхронно.

@Wlad, конечно извиняюсь, но как можно это реализовать? Просто не очень понимаю что такое потоки, пока что только изучаю это

@Cetonix почитайте для начала про https://javarush.com/groups/posts/1993-mnogopotochnostjh-chto-delajut-metodih-klassa-thread это классические потоки в Java. что касается Андроида - то тут либо RxJava (отдельная библиотека) либо Корутины (для этого вам надо переходить на язык Котлин. что я вам и рекомендую делать, т.к. под Андроид на Java никто сейчас не пишет). либо, попробуйте запускать ваш аудио-плеер в ForegroundService'е (гуглите, читайте).
